# jQuery .hover won't work in Chrome or Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have a few buttons in a navbar that I want to highlight on hover, works fine in Firefox, IE and Opera but not in Chrome or Safari. Been searching for a while and already read the topics here on stackoverflow but didn't find a working solution.

The html:

```
    <div class="bgc dropshadow2" id="navbar" >
        <ul>
            <a href="" alt=""><li class="navButton"><span>Word</span></li></a>
            <a href="" alt=""><li class="navButton"><span>Word</span></li></a>
            <a href="" alt=""><li class="navButton"><span>Word</span></li></a>
            <a href="" alt=""><li class="navButton"><span>Word</span></li></a>
            <a href="" alt=""><li class="navButton marginLast"><span>Word</span></li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The Css:

```
#navbar ul li {
float: left;
height: 24px;
width: 100px;
margin-left: 24px;
margin-right: 8px;
padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
text-align: center;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
```

}

The jQuery:

```
    $(function(){
        $('.navButton').hover( function(){
            $(this).css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2');
        });
    });
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis in `$(this).css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2');`. Try `$(this).css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)');`. Are you getting a Javascript error in Chrome's console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo on this line -  `$(this).css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2');`

Change:

```
$(this).css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2');
```

To:

```
$(this).css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)');
```